# ChromeでSMILをサポートしますか?

Tags: javascript, css, html5, svg

Chome45でSMILを非推奨したと知っています。
しかし,最新Chomeでうまく動作し,Consoleでも警告がなくなったようです。
Caniuse(https://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-smil) にも支援していることで表示します。
SVGのSMIL志願するんですか?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

今は "deprecation" にするのは "suspended" (保留?/一時停止?) 状態のようですね。

以下の Issue が出ていて、
[SVG SMIL Chrome deprecation is "suspended" since 2016-08-17 #4167](https://github.com/Fyrd/caniuse/issues/4167)

MDN にも注釈があります。
[SVG animation with SMIL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_animation_with_SMIL)

Comment: かなり大きな反発があったんですね。それでCSS AnimationsとWeb Animationsをメジャーブラウザがすべて支援する前までsuspendedするということのようですね!

ご返答ありがとうございます！